# Shortcode Site include in a other

Tags: shortcode

I would like to use the Shortcode Plugin but I don't know which file I have to put it.

Please provide me, that I can use the nice Plugin.

Comment: sorry but at the current state of the question it is just impossible to understand what is it that you ask

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to understand what you are trying to ask?

Do you want to know how to use a plugin's shortcode? if so, then you can copy the shortcode in the content section of the new post or page. For Example, if the shortcode for the plugin is `[plugin-shortcode]`.  Then just publish or preview the page to see the output.

[image]